# Boost shared_ptr use_count function

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

My application problem is the following -

I have a large structure foo.  Because these are large and for memory management reasons, we do not wish to delete them when processing on the data is complete.

We are storing them in `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<foo>>.`

My question is related to knowing when all processing is complete.  First decision is that we do not want any of the other application code to mark a complete flag in the structure because there are multiple execution paths in the program and we cannot predict which one is the last.

So in our implementation, once processing is complete, we delete all copies of `boost::shared_ptr<foo>>` except for the one in the vector.  This will drop the reference counter in the shared_ptr to 1.  Is it practical to use shared_ptr.use_count() to see if it is equal to 1 to know when all other parts of my app are done with the data.

One additional reason I'm asking the question is that the boost documentation on the shared pointer [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) recommends not using "use_count" for production code.

---

Edit - 
What I did not say is that when we need a new foo, we will scan the vector of foo pointers looking for a foo that is not currently in use and use that foo for the next round of processing.  This is why I was thinking that having the reference counter of 1 would be a safe way to ensure that this particular foo object is no longer in use.

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded?  This will change the answers if it is.

Comment: yes, with 3 to 6 threads working on data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My immediate reaction (and I'll admit, it's no more than that) is that it sounds like you're trying to get the effect of a pool allocator of some sort. You might be better off overloading `operator new` and `operator delete` to get the effect you want a bit more directly. With something like that, you can probably just use a `shared_ptr` like normal, and the other work you want delayed, will be handled in `operator delete` for that class.

That leaves a more basic question: what are you really trying to accomplish with this? From a memory management viewpoint, one common wish is to allocate memory for a large number of objects at once, and after the entire block is empty, release the whole block at once. If you're trying to do something on that order, it's almost certainly easier to accomplish by overloading `new` and `delete` than by playing games with `shared_ptr`'s `use_count`.

Edit: based on your comment, overloading `new` and `delete` for class sounds like the right thing to do. If anything, integration into your existing code will probably be easier; in fact, you can often do it completely transparently.

The general idea for the allocator is pretty much the same as you've outlined in your edited question: have a structure (bitmaps and linked lists are both common) to keep track of your free objects. When `new` needs to allocate an object, it can scan the bit vector or look at the head of the linked list of free objects, and return its address.

This is one case that linked lists can work out quite well -- you (usually) don't have to worry about memory usage, because you store your links right in the free object, and you (virtually) never have to walk the list, because when you need to allocate an object, you just grab the first item on the list.

This sort of thing is particularly common with small objects, so you might want to look at the *Modern C++ Design* chapter on its small object allocator (and an article or two since then by Andrei Alexandrescu about his newer ideas of how to do that sort of thing). There's also the Boost::pool allocator, which is generally at least somewhat similar.

Comment: You have summed up my problem very well.  We are trying to use this as pool of objects that we can get the next free one from.
Whatever we do, we also have to look at see if we can also retrofit it to our existing code base as well as our new app.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know whether or not the use count is 1, use the `unique()` member function.

Answer (score 2):

I would say your application should have some method that eliminates all references to the Foo from other parts of the app, and that method should be used instead of checking `use_count()`.  Besides, if `use_count()` is greater than 1, what would your program do?  You shouldn't be relying on `shared_ptr`'s features to eliminate all references, your application architecture should be able to eliminate references.  As a final check before removing it from the vector, you could `assert(unique())` to verify it really is being released.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `shared_ptr`'s custom deleter functionality to call a particular function when the last copy has been released.  That way, you're not using `use_count` at all.

You would need to hold something other than a copy of the `shared_ptr` in your `vector` so that the `shared_ptr` is only tracking the outstanding processing.

Boost has [several examples of custom deleters](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html) in the `shared_ptr` docs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead of trying to use the shared_ptr's use_count to keep track, it might be better to implement your own usage counter. this way you will have full control over this rather than using the shared_ptr's one which, as you rightly suggest, is not recommended. You can also pre-set your own counter to allow for the number of threads you know will need to act on the data, rather than relying on them all being initialised at the beginning to get their copies of the structure.